# Train Fare Database Normalisation

Tags: database-design, normalization, database-recommendation

I have a database to normalize. The database has details of train ticket fares.

The trains have different fares depending on the distance and I have to store these fares in the database

It is not an option to calculate the fare based on distance because the fare is followed strictly by the fare chart. The only way I can think of to store the values is like this is in the following table. However using this half the table is going to have NULL values.

```
+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Station Name | Distance  | Station A | Station B | Station C |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Station A    |         0 | 0         | 10        |        25 |
| Station B    |         1 | NULL      | 0         |        10 |
| Station C    |         2 | NULL      | NULL      |         0 |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Can you suggest a better way to normalize the database.

Comment: How about route variations - does the model have to cover that? E.g. can the train go A->B->C->D and also A->D via a different route?

Comment: No we are talking about a single track here. The train will go from A->B->C->D

Comment: Is the fare of the complete route always equal to the sum of fares between each pair of adjacent stations? E.g. is the sum of fares A->B + B->C the same as the fare A->(via B)->C? According to your example, not necessarily (A->B = 10, B->C = 10, A->(via B)->C = 25).

Comment: No. That is why I mentioned that it is strictly followed by the fare chart.

Comment: The most obvious way would be: `T(src, dest, distance)`. Example tuples (A,B,10), (A,C,25), (B,C,10). If this relation is symmetric a view like `select src, dest, distance from T union all select dest, src, distance from T` can be used. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

You want to convert the pivot table into a normalized table.  Store each cell in your chart as a row in a `FARE` table.  The business key of this table is `Origin` + `Destination` and the non-key columns are `Distance` and `Amount`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose one of the terminal stations as `origin` and store the distances from `origin` to the each station on the route:

```
+--------------+----------------------+
| Station Name | Distance from origin |
+--------------+----------------------+
| Station A    |                    0 |
| Station B    |                   10 |
| Station C    |                   20 |
| Station D    |                   27 |
+--------------+----------------------+
```

When you want to calculate the distance between stations you have to take the absolute value of the difference between their distances.

```
SELECT a.s_name AS from, b.s_name AS to, ABS(a.dfo - b.dfo) AS distance
  FROM stations AS a 
  JOIN stations AS b
 WHERE a.s_name = 'Station C' 
   AND b.s_name = 'Station B';
```